# How to compare a folder size in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have to apply a command IF the folder size is greater or equal to 600MB.

I tried something like this

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem d:\home -exclude *.*
function Get-Size
{
 param([string]$pth)
 "{0:n2}" -f ((gci -path $pth -recurse | measure-object -property length -sum).sum /1mb)
}


ForEach ($subFolder in $folders){

echo $subFolder | select-object fullname
$size = Get-Size $subFolder
echo $size

    if ($size -gt "600") { echo "Not ok." }
    else { echo "OK template." }

}
```

It doesn't work. It writes the right size of the folder but the IF statement is not respected. How do I do?

Comment: tried to remove the double quotes ? `if ($size -gt 600)`

Comment: yup, still same. Doesn't give any error, it just says false things!

Comment: dont use `-f` and compare directly `((gci -path $pth -recurse | measure-object -property length -sum).sum /1mb) -gt 600` . `-f` produce a string element while the latter produce a double. You can check that by piping the command to `get-member`

Comment: Life saver... It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `FileSystemObject` COM object:

```
function Get-FolderSize($path) {
    (New-Object -ComObject 'Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetFolder($path).Size
}
```

I'd recommend against doing formatting in a `Get-Size` function, though. It's usually better to have the function return the raw size, and do calculations and formatting when you actually display the value.

Use it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\home' | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -and
    Get-FolderSize $_.FullName -gt 600MB
}
```

or like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\home' | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer
} | ForEach-Object {
    if (Get-FolderSize $_.FullName -gt 600MB) {
        'Not OK.'
    } else {
        'OK template.'
    }
}
```

On PowerShell v3 and newer you can use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` instead of `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing using $size -gt "600" the value is considered as string. Hence not getting right results.

Try comparison using integers.

Comment: You may want to edit your answer instead of burying relevant information in comments.

Comment: Use this command to get desired results:   


`$treeSize = @{}; Get-ChildItem '.\Program Files' | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true } | ForEach-Object { $treeSize += @{$($_.Name)=$((Get-ChildItem -Path $($_.FullName) -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue').Sum/1MB)}}; $treeSize.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value -Descending | Where-Object { $_.Value -gt 600 }`  


You can replace **`'.\Program Files'`** with desired folder name

Comment: "Edit" means the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31584645/edit) link right below your answer.

Comment: I am sorry @Ansgar, I am new to this. I was trying to figure out how to reach desired formatting while posting this reply. However, somehow it was not allowing me to edit my comments anymore. Thus I had to add additional text as a new reply post. I believe I learned how to do that now :-)