# Show used space for each folder on a share (No WMI etc.)

Tags: powershell, storage

I'm trying to display used space on a share. Let's assume I have a share \\server\share$, and there are home folders of many users. I cant use WMI because its a NetApp. Can I somehow list all the directories with their measured space?

What I have tested so far:

```cs
$head = "<style>
td {font-family:candara;width:100px; max-width:300px; background-color:white;}
table {width:100%;}
th {font-family:candara;font-size:14pt;background-color:#9e1981;}
h1 {font-family:candara;font-size:18pt}
p1 {font-family:candara;font-size:9pt}
</style>

<title>Disk Use</title>"

$PPath    = "\\Server\it$\Scriptrepository\Logs\"
$file     = $PPath + "Server_Home_Size.html"
$itemlist = Get-ChildItem \\Server\home$
$ObjectList = @()
foreach ($item in $itemlist) {
    #Set-Location \\Server\home$
    $size = "{0:N2} GB" -f ((gci $item.FullName | measure Length -s).Sum / 1Gb)
    $fullName = $item.FullName
    $list = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $list | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $fullName
    $list | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Size" -Value $Size
    $data += $list
    $ObjectList += $data
}

$ObjectList |
    ConvertTo-Html -As table -Head $head -PreContent "<h1>Server Home</h1>" |
    Out-File $file
```

But I'm getting the following error, and this is just not working properly:

```
Fehler beim Aufrufen der Methode, da [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
keine Methode mit dem Namen "op_Addition" enthält.
In S:\ScriptRepository\_InBearbeitung\SIvanov\Server_Homesize.ps1:21 Zeichen:1
+ $data += $list
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
```

And this one:

```
Measure-Object : Die Eigenschaft "length" kann in keiner Eingabe eines Objekts
gefunden werden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:61
+ ... ildItem $item.FullName | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum /  ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GenericMeasurePropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

Comment: `$data` is not defined as an array. Also, why are you trying to append `$list` to `$data` in the first place? Just append `$list` to `$ObjectList` directly.

Comment: Okay i have defined `$data`, still, I'm getting the second error about the property length

Comment: Check what type of object you have when the error occurs (e.g. by putting the relevant section of the code in a `try`/`catch` statement). Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31586240/1630171) is probably a far simpler way to achieve your objective.

Comment: NetApp have a Powershell module of cmdlets available which you can download from their site. You should be able to query the NetApp directly for the information you need.

Comment: it seems like when its a directory I do not get the `length` property, but when they are files i have it. I use `Get-Childitem` now with `-recurse` to get all the files. I think now it should be okay